# Выводится предыдущее состояние при событии change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Почему при событии change в state'е выводится предыдущее состояние, а не измененное

```
    import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import serialize from "form-serialize";

class ObjectFilter extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log(this);

        this.state = {

            componentLoad: false,
            item: [],
            chosenBuilder: ''

        };

        this.changeBuilder = this.changeBuilder.bind(this);

    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.ajaxFunc();

    }

    ajaxFunc() {

        axios({

            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://blabla/api/getDevelopers.php',
            responseType: 'json',


        })
            .then(res => {


                this.setState(
                    ({item, componentLoad}) => ({

                        item: res.data,
                        componentLoad: true
                    })
                );


                // console.log('ok');
                // console.log(res);


            })
            .catch(function (er) {

                console.log('error');
                console.log(er);
            });

    }


    changeBuilder(e) {

        let form = document.querySelector('#form-filter');
        let data = serialize(form);
        let valSelect = e.target.value;
        this.setState(
            {chosenBuilder: valSelect}
        );
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    regionSelect() {
        return (


            <select id="field-1">
                <option>Москва</option>

            </select>

        );
    }

    builderSelect() {
        // console.log(this.state.item);

        return (
            <select id="field-2" name={"DEVELOPER"} onChange={this.changeBuilder}>

                <option value={""}>Все</option>
                {this.state.item.map((obj, i) =>


                    <option key={i} value={obj.ID}>{obj.NAME}</option>
                )}

            </select>
        );
    }


    render() {

        if (this.state.componentLoad) {

            return (
                <div className="object-filter">
                    <div className="general-form">


                        <form id="form-filter">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <label htmlFor="field-1">Регион</label>
                                    <div className="general-form-select">
                                        {this.regionSelect()}
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label htmlFor="field-2">Застройщик</label>
                                    <div className="general-form-select">
                                        {this.builderSelect()}
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label htmlFor="field-1">Цена от</label>
                                    <input id="field-3" name={"PRICE_FROM"}/>

                                </li>
                                <li>


                                    <label htmlFor="field-2" name={"PRICE_TO"}>Цена до</label>
                                    <input id="field-4"/>


                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>


            );
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

export default ObjectFilter;
```

[image: Если выберу "Все" то в в стейт добавиться значение 21 тобиш]

Как решить проблему, почему так происходит?

зато если в devtools открыть то вот там все ок, это как???
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь вывести `state` тогда когда он еще не изменен полностью. Чтобы получить значение после успешного изменения, нужно сипользовать хук `componentDidUpdate`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import serialize from "form-serialize";

class ObjectFilter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(this);

    this.state = {
      componentLoad: false,
      item: [],
      chosenBuilder: ""
    };

    this.changeBuilder = this.changeBuilder.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ajaxFunc();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state); // изменения видны здесь, потому что данный хук срабатывает после того как стейт изменен
  }

  ajaxFunc() {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://blabla/api/getDevelopers.php",
      responseType: "json"
    })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState(({ item, componentLoad }) => ({
          item: res.data,
          componentLoad: true
        }));

        // console.log('ok');
        // console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(function(er) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(er);
      });
  }

  changeBuilder(e) {
    let form = document.querySelector("#form-filter");
    let data = serialize(form);
    let valSelect = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ chosenBuilder: valSelect });
    console.log(this.state); // изменения не видны здесь, потому что стейт еще не изменен
  }

  regionSelect() {
    return (
      <select id="field-1">
        <option>Москва</option>
      </select>
    );
  }

  builderSelect() {
    // console.log(this.state.item);

    return (
      <select id="field-2" name={"DEVELOPER"} onChange={this.changeBuilder}>
        <option value={""}>Все</option>
        {this.state.item.map((obj, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={obj.ID}>
            {obj.NAME}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.componentLoad) {
      return (
        <div className="object-filter">
          <div className="general-form">
            <form id="form-filter">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <label htmlFor="field-1">Регион</label>
                  <div className="general-form-select">
                    {this.regionSelect()}
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <label htmlFor="field-2">Застройщик</label>
                  <div className="general-form-select">
                    {this.builderSelect()}
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <label htmlFor="field-1">Цена от</label>
                  <input id="field-3" name={"PRICE_FROM"} />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <label htmlFor="field-2" name={"PRICE_TO"}>
                    Цена до
                  </label>
                  <input id="field-4" />
                </li>
              </ul>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

export default ObjectFilter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `setState` - асинхронная, она принимает 2 параметра:

1. Функцию которая возвращает новый стейт или объект с новым стейтом
2. Функция коллбек которая будет вызвана после изменения состояния

Чтобы вывести измененное состояние нужно сделать вот так:

```
this.setState(state, () => {console.log(this.state)})
```